# Python: creating class instance

Tags: python, python-2.7, webapp2

There is some part of code.

```
application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
    ('/gbook', Guestbook)
])
```

As I understand it is a list of tuples:

```
[('/', MainPage), ('/gbook', Guestbook)]
```

Correct me please if I'm wrong.

And I have question: Where is obvious creation of instance of MainPage class and Guestbook?

Something like that: `x = MainPage('/')`

If this happens by this tuple `('/', MainPage)`, then my question: how it's happens?

I need some explanation.

Comment: Yes, that is a list of tuples. *"Where is obvious creation of instance..."* - nowhere in the code you're showing. Explanation of code is off-topic here, particularly if you don't even show the code in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `WSGIApplication` it self creates the instances of the classes. In python you can pass classes around, just like you would pass instances of a class. For example:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print "A Created"

def foo(cls):
    inst = cls()

foo(A)
```

If you run this script it will print out "A Created" because you are passing in the class to `foo` which is creating a new instance from that class.

Comment: Small another question: is there some way to get access to variables of class A?

Comment: Yes, it's just like everything else in python.

Comment: but in this case I have no any name of instance of class. How it is possible without global var?

Comment: There is a difference between a class and an instance. In the example of `inst` is an Object that is an instance of `A`. If `A` had static variables or functions than inside `foo` you could access them with `cls.staticFunction()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check source code of webapp2 to verify this.

In `__init__` function of `WSGIApplication` , list `'[('/', MainPage),('/gbook', Guestbook)]'` will be passed as variable `routes`, then they will be instantiated by `Route` class.